# Validate if age is over 18 years old with Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, validation, date, angular-reactive-forms

Is there a way to check if a user is over 18 years of age  when they have entered their date of birth using Angular Validators?

My form looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="authForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <label>Date of birth</label>
    <input formControlName="day" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD" type="text" />
    <input formControlName="month" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM" type="text" />
    <input formControlName="year" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY" type="text" />
    <button [disabled]="!authForm.valid" type="submit"> Check age </button>
</form>
```

And then I have these validators set in the TS file:

```
if (this.authType === 'register') {
    this.authForm.addControl('year', new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.minLength(4)]));
    this.authForm.addControl('month', new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2)]));
    this.authForm.addControl('day', new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2)]));
 }
```

So if the conditions above are satisfied in the Validators, the button becomes enabled. But I also need to check that the entered date is over 18 years old before enabling it. This seems tricky as the date is entered via 3 inputs (dd, mm, yyyy). And in this case, I can't use the input date tag. Any suggestions or comments appreciated. Thanks!

**P.S. Thanks for all the suggestions about using MomentJS. I'm already using it elsewhere in the app so I'll also use it here.**

Comment: hey u can use moment.js to write date validation as mentioned by @joto.toledo and for more reference https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configurate a custom validator that will be hooked to the complete `FormGroup` in this case.
A [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) based approach would look like this:

```js
export function minimumAge(age:number): ValidatorFn {
  return (fg: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
      let result: ValidationErrors = null;
      if (fg.get('year').valid && fg.get('month').valid && fg.get('day').valid) {
        // carefull, moment months range is from 0 to 11
        const value: { year: string, month: string, day: string } = fg.value;
        const date = moment({ year: +value.year, month: (+value.month) - 1, day: +value.day }).startOf('day');
        if (date.isValid()) {
          // https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/
          const now = moment().startOf('day');
          const yearsDiff = date.diff(now, 'years');
          if (yearsDiff > -age) {
            result = {
              'minimumAge': {
                'requiredAge': age,
                'actualAge': yearsDiff
              }
            };
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
}

export class DateEditComponent {
  readonly authForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.authForm = this._fb.group({
        year: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.minLength(4)]],
        month: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2)]],
        day: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2)]]
    });
    this.authForm.setValidators(minimumAge(18));
  }
}
```

For a live example please check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-form-group?file=app/date-edit.component.ts)

Notice that in this case Im not taking care of any format/range validation on the singular input fields.

Comment: This worked perfectly. MANY thanks! And thanks for putting the code example together too!

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd have to make your custom validator. This validator would also have to be placed on the entire FormGroup, instead of just a single FormControl as the validation needs to run whenever any of the 3 inputs value changes.

How you implement the validation is up to you since this involves dates, but I always use momentjs to work with dates.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I was thinking that a custom validator would be best too.