# How to validate this birthday form in sign up form in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am trying to validate this birthday form?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Day">
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Month</option>
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
  </select>
</div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Year">
</div>
    </div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
       'username': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])'),
       ]),
       'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])'),
       ]),
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails),
      'password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}'),
       ]),
       'phone': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('(?=.*[0-9])'),
       ]),
    });
}
```

I am using a reactive form builder to validate other fields like Username, password... 
I also found this question here where was suggested to use moment.js but was confused. Can't figure out how to use moment js with this form for validating above mentioned birthday field with the moment.

Comment: Hey man, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Hey! How to validate above HTML birthday form inside my typescript form group? I assume should use Moment.js but can't figure out how to use for this specific case for this specific form?

Comment: @jburtondev it's very poor behavior just downvote and remove answer only because you can't answer to the question. I didn't downvote your answer. So it was not necessary to downvote the question!

Comment: Fair enough, I am trying to upvote your answer again. The issue I have with your comment was that I took the time to understand your answer, but then you highlighted problems with the solution (which is ok) but your comments were contradictory. 

Just want to help mate.

Comment: As you might see from other questions I  mark all them solved if see a solution that works but never downvote any answer so it's not needed to delete the answer :)
I looked at this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192404/angular4-typescript-birthday-validation-day-month-year

But not sure how he used it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new form group for your birthday form, then you can validate each control: Day, Month, Year against a regular expression that ensures the combines value adheres to the format you desire (11/11/18) for example.

You don't need Moment.js unless you are trying to prepopulate a date, even then this isn't to do with validation, but rather the date it produces will need to be validated.

Comment: Why don't validate it in existing form group? Also Late I will need to create a pipe for converting it into the age of the user is that possible without a moment?

Comment: You can, but the select tag isn't linked to the form yet. It needs the form control attribute.

Comment: There is another problem in this solution. There are months with 31 days and months 30 days also February 28 or 29 days. So that is why this solution is not enough by just Form group features. The point is that how to use Moment with it

Answer (score 0):

I read your comments and I believe you really do not want these to be `select` input. You should go with proper `datepicker` plugin with reactive form.

You should go through `ng-bootstrap` which provides `ngbDatepicker` which can help you in all the way you want - Validation and actual datepicker. It provides integration with reactive form.

Hope this helps.!

Comment: Thanks for replying but I am trying to ignore all additional libraries. I don't use ng-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer that solves a similar problem:

[Validate if age is over 18 years old with Angular Reactive Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521396/validate-if-age-is-over-18-years-old-with-angular-reactive-forms)

It's quite detailed. Also, a working example is included. You can just ignore the last part if you don't need to check if people are over 18 years old.